# Wordpress integration with asp.net

Tags: wordpress

Is there any Wordpress API key to integrate with asp.net or any other way to integrate wordpress blog with asp.net?
If yes then how it is work?

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with Wordpress over XMLRPC.php in your blog's root directory.

And you can (ofcourse) directly edit the database. But this is dangerous!  Be sure to know what you are doing.

If you want a blog that works on ASP.NET I would suggest using DasBlog :)

Comment: My website in asp.net.
In this website when member register at that time wordpress blog will be created for that member.
For another member another wordpress blog will be created for that member.
When member change password in our means asp.net website also password will be change for his or her wordpress blog.
It means asp.net is directly interact with wordpress blog.
Is it possible?
If yes then how it will be work?
Please help me in detail.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be quite cumbersome to go this way. Why not use a ASP.NET blog? That would make stuff much easier and faster!

Comment: ya you r right. But customer wants wordpress blog. By the way customer is god.